# Undefined method 'subject' NoMethodError Ruby on Rails, Michael Hartl Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

currently I'm stuck on an error that has been plaguing me for quite some time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Explanation : I've tried to run 'bundle exec rspec spec/' command in my console to test whether all the scripts are working however I'm greeted with the error "undefined method 'subject' for main:object (NoMethodError)

Code for spec/requests/static_pages.rb file

```
     require 'spec_helper

     describe "Static pages" do

    describe "Home page" do
       before {visit root_path}
      it "should have the content 'Sample App'" do
        expect(page).to have_content('Sample App')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Home'" do
      expect(page).to have_title("Home")
    end
  end

  describe "Help page" do
      before {visit help_path}
    it "should have the content 'Help'" do
      expect(page).to have_content('Help')
    end

    it "should have the title 'Help'" do
      expect(page).to have_title("Help")
    end
  end

  describe "About page" do
    before {visit about_path}
    it "should have the content 'About Us'" do
      expect(page).to have_content('About Us')
    end

    it "should have the title 'About Us'" do
      expect(page).to have_title("About Us")
    end
  end

  describe "Contact Page" do    
    before {visit contact_path}
    it "should have the content 'Contact'" do
        expect(page).to have_content('Contact')
    end
    it "should have the title 'Contact'" do
        expect(page).to have_title("Contact")
    end
  end
end
```

and for spec/models/user_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com", password: "foobar", password_confimation: "foobar")
  end

  subject { @user }

  it { should respond_to(:name) }
  it { should respond_to(:email) }
  it { should respond_to(:password_digest)}
  it { should respond_tp(:password)}
  it { should respond_to(:password_confimation)}
  it { should respond_to(:authenticate)}


  it { should be_valid }

  describe "with a password that's too short" do
    before { @user.password = @user.password_confirmation = "a" * 5 }
    it { should be_invalid }
  end

  describe "return value of authenticate method" do
    before { @user.save }
    let(:found_user) { User.find_by(email: @user.email) }

    describe "with valid password" do
      it { should eq found_user.authenticate(@user.password) }
    end

    describe "with invalid password" do
      let(:user_for_invalid_password) { found_user.authenticate("invalid") }

      it { should_not eq user_for_invalid_password }
      specify { expect(user_for_invalid_password).to be_false }
    end
  end
```

code for specified file 'generic.rb'

```
'subject {page}

describe "Home page" do
    before {visit root_path}
    it {should have_content ('Sample App')}
    it {should have_title(full_title(''))}
    it {should_not have_title('| Home')}
end'
```

Comment: Hi, could you paste error message together with backtrace?

Comment: Please take more care when pasting your code examples.

Comment: Since you are a beginner I like to point you to this article: http://nofail.de/2013/10/debugging-rails-applications-in-development/

Comment: Hi, phoet I'm new on this forum so I'm still trying to figure out things. Thank you for the article link. BriotStatse the full error message : spec/support/generic.rb:1:in '(top (required))':undefined method 'subject' for main:object (noMethodError)

Comment: Can you then show us the file specified in error message?

Comment: I added the file's code at the bottom. (Sorry for the poor formatting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `subject` declaration inside describe block:

```
describe "Home page" do
    subject {page}
    before {visit root_path}
    it {should have_content ('Sample App')}
    it {should have_title(full_title(''))}
    it {should_not have_title('| Home')}
end
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone who helped. This worked, only to bring up another array of errors, haha. Thank you.